# Tools to help developers reading class hierarchy faster

Tags: python, django, class

I mostly spend time on Python/Django and Objective-C/CocoaTouch and js/jQuery in the course of my daily work.

My editor of choice is `vim` for Python/Django and js/jQuery and `xcode` for Objective-C/CocoaTouch.

One of the bottlenecks on my development speed is the pace at which I read existing code, particularly open source libraries which I use.

In Python/Django for example, when I encounter some new features introduced by django developers, I get curious and begin exploring the code base manually.  For example, when class-based views were introduced from django 1.3 onwards, reference - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/ - I will check out the example code shown:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class AboutView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "about.html"
```

And try it out on one of my projects.  More importantly, I am curious about what goes on behind the scenes, so I will dig into the source code -

```
# django/views/generic/__init__.py file

from django.views.generic.base import View, TemplateView, RedirectView
from django.views.generic.dates import (ArchiveIndexView, YearArchiveView, MonthArchiveView,
                                     WeekArchiveView, DayArchiveView, TodayArchiveView,
                                     DateDetailView)
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView


class GenericViewError(Exception):
    """A problem in a generic view."""
    pass
```

From here, I will trace it backwards to the django/views/generic/base.py file and find out exactly what `TemplateView` class does:-

```
class TemplateView(TemplateResponseMixin, View):
    """
    A view that renders a template.
    """
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        return {
            'params': kwargs
        }

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

And here's it shows that `TemplateView` class inherits from `TemplateResponseMixin` and `View` classes... and I continue digging further... and so on...

**The problem is, this is an extremely inefficient and slow process (to "follow" class hierachies manually and opening up each file along the way).**

So the question is - is there an easy way/UI tool (or other visual solution) that parses Python code in a particular project and visualize class hierarchies which I can then inspect easily by "clicking" on a specific class I am interested to read about?

**Note** that I am aware of IPython shell but that doesn't seem as user-friendly as a visual display tool.

For example, there's `F-Script` in the world of Objective-C/iOS/Mac programming, which not only provides a shell (much like python or IPython shell), but provides a visual way for developers to introspect class hierachies.

Reference screenshot:-

[image]

So is there a class-hierarchy visualization tool (for Python specifically, but even better if it's generic and can be used for different languages)???  What are your methods of getting up to speed efficiently when reading open source source code???

**UPDATED**

Per advice below, I tried out `ctags` and vim plugin `taglist` and I was able to use `:TlistOpen` to open up a side buffer in vim like this:-

[image]

This looks really cool as `:TlistOpen` now essentially shows me all the classes and functions that are available on my currently open buffer.

My problem now is that when I attempt to do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> while my cursor is on `TemplateView`, I get the following error:-

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is it because my django source code is in a `virtualenv`? Or is there something specific I have to do to make `ctags`/`taglist` "aware" of the django source code?

Comment: Not Constructive for Stack Overflow, I feel, but quite on topic on http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Try exuberant ctags (as recommended by @Kay Zhu), I believe there's a command/script to generate tags from the source in your current env/virtualenv.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tags are a very good start indeed. (There's too much stuff all over the place on it, so I'll just provide you with one extra keyword to search with: ctags.)

In Vim, it ends up (in the basic case) with <kbd>Ctrl+]</kbd> to go to a class/function definition and <kbd>Ctrl+T</kbd> to return.

Comment: Hi Chris, am getting an error when I attempted `Ctrl+]`... am I missing something?

Comment: Managed to get it working, albeit a very manual process. Would you happen to know more about the use of ctags/taglist plugin in the context of python virtualenv? Reference - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362085/ctags-with-taglist-in-vim-and-python-virtualenv

Comment: No, I don't. Generating tags is always something that must be set up. The way I've ever used ctags wouldn't require anything special for the virtualenv; if you want tags for something inside the virtualenv, specify it as a path to make tags for.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using [exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) with [taglist](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273) for vim. Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> to jump to class definition in the current window, <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>w</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> to jump to the definition in a split window.

You can install exuberant ctags via homebrew:

```
brew install ctags
```

Be sure to use the one installed at `/usr/local/bin` by homebrew, not the old `ctags` in `/usr/bin`.

It is also helpful to put `--python-kinds=-vi` in `~/.ctags` to skip indexing variables and imports for Python files.

Another alternative would be to use a variant of `cscope` or `pyscope` though you must have your vim compiled with `cscope` option enabled.

Comment: Hello Kay, I just got `ctags` and vim plugin `taglist` installed. It looks promising but I am using `virtualenv` so does that affect whether or not `ctags` and `taglist` can find the class I want to browse?  Updating the question above with the errors I am seeing...

Comment: @CalvinCheng yes it would, just remember to use `ctags -R` and remember to be at the same `pwd` as the parent directory of the `virtualenv` directory :)

Answer (score 3):

The IDLE editor included with Python has [an effective class browser](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3bac1e1a0e0d/Lib/idlelib/ClassBrowser.py) that efficiently navigates everything in a given module.  I believe in would not be difficult to modify that tool to navigate a full class-hierarchy with some assistance from the [inspect module](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#module-inspect) and the [pyclbr module](http://docs.python.org/library/pyclbr.html#module-pyclbr).

Comment: Hello Raymond! I remember you from EuroPython 2011 at Florence.
Nice to see your responses here to my questions!!! Cool!