# ctags with taglist in vim and python virtualenv

Tags: python, vim, virtualenv, ctags, taglist

I use `virtualenv` and `django` in my projects and I am trying to find a more efficient way to browse django source code.

As advised here - [Tools to help developers reading class hierarchy faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361714/tools-to-help-developers-reading-class-hierarchy-faster) - I got myself set-up with ctags via

```
sudo port -v install ctags
```

and installed the vim plugin `taglist` via https://github.com/vim-scripts/taglist.vim

Unfortunately, it seems that `ctags` cannot locate my django's class when I attempted to "jump" to view a class via <kbd>Ctrl+]</kbd>.

Any suggestions how I can get `ctags` to read python source code located in my virtualenv?

**UPDATES**

With further experimentation, I realized that `ctags` is some kind of "indexing" program which parses through a given directory/files/file and grabs all the keywords (class names, method names, function names etc) it finds and writes it into a file.  This file can be updated and vim plugin `taglist` essentially reads from it to know where to send me to when I do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> on a class/method/function name.

So I came up with a temporary and manual solution, which I execute in my vim, like this:-

```
:set tags=~/mytags
:! ctags -R -o ~/mytags ~/.virtualenvs/myprojectname
```

The first command tells my vim/taglist where my "indexed" results are stored.

The second command writes the indexed results into `~/mytags` file by searching recursively (`-R`) down the `~/.virtualenvs/myprojectname`

This works but is a very manual way to maintain tags and tags change if I happen to be in a different `virtualenv` environment.

Does anyone know of an automated way to manage this `ctags` process?

Answer (score 5):

[There are many "automatic tags generation" plugins available.](http://www.vim.org/scripts/index.php)

TagList doesn't read from whatever `tags` you have manually/automatically generated: it's calling `ctags` itself and reads its output directly.

Also you might want to read `:help autocommand`. You could setup autocommands to re-generate your `tags` on write like this:

```
autocmd BufWritePost,FileWritePost *.py :silent! !ctags -R -o ~/mytags ~/.virtualenvs/myprojectname
```

Comment: was your link pointing to some where? I am getting a 404.  And regarding your example autocommand, it's a little more complicated that that because `vim` has to detect which python virtualenv I am in when it opens up a specific file and I am not sure there's a way to autodetect which virtualenv a project file "belongs" to.

Comment: Link fixed. Also see [this plugin](https://github.com/jmcantrell/vim-virtualenv), it's supposed to make it easier to deal with virtualenv.